# Symfony2 exception event listener run some controller actions

Tags: symfony

I need to do one of two things (in priority order, but just need one of them).

All of this is to be done inside a function that runs as an Exception Event Listener (http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/GetResponseForExceptionEvent.html).

Both below are totally easy inside a normal controller, but I can't see it possible inside an event listener function.

(1) Run a controller as normal and output as normal as though that route had been executed:

```
e.g. $event->runController('controllerName');
```

(2) render a template as normal using the same syntax as would inside a normal controller:

```
return $this->render('Bundle:Default:feedback.html.twig', array([template vars]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at symfony's default exception listener in `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener`.

## (1) running a controller can be realized this way:

```
    $request = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request();
    $request->setMethod('GET');
    [..]

    try {
        $response = $event->getKernel()->handle($request, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST, true);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return; // pass it to next exception listener this way 
    }

    $event->setResponse($response);
```

## (2) rendering a template in exception listener

all you need to do is pass templating (engine) to the listener inside the service.yml

```
    services:
      foobar.exception_listener_service:
        class: %foobar.exception_listener_service.class%
        arguments:
          container: "@service_container"
        tags:
          - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException, priority: 255 }
```

inside the listener you can render templates as listed below

```
    $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
    $response = new Response($templating->render('foobar:Exception:error404.html.twig', array('exception' => $exception)));
    $event->setResponse($response);
```